# NameError undefined local variable when using console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my console I am doing 'user = Zip.find(30052).users.first' which returns the first user. I then run the command 'user.within_miles(25).count(:all)" so that I can find everyone within 25 miles of the user. This gives a error, 'undefined local variable or method `zip''

It seems like the error is pointing to method missing in the user.rb for 'within_miles'. But I have it defined in there.

user.rb:

```
  scope :within_miles_of_zip, lambda{|radius, zip|
     # Get the parameters for the search
     area = zip.area_for(radius)

     { :select => "#{User.columns.map{|c| "users.#{c.name}"}.join(', ')}, sqrt( 
         pow(#{area[:lat_miles]} * (zips.lat - #{zip.lat}),2) + 
         pow(#{area[:lon_miles]} * (zips.lon - #{zip.lon}),2)) as distance",
       :joins => :zip,
       :conditions => "(zips.lat BETWEEN #{area[:min_lat]} AND #{area[:max_lat]}) 
         AND (zips.lon BETWEEN #{area[:min_lon]} AND #{area[:max_lon]}) 
         AND sqrt(pow(#{area[:lat_miles]} * (zips.lat - #{zip.lat}),2) + 
         pow(#{area[:lon_miles]} * (zips.lon - #{zip.lon}),2)) <= #{area[:radius]}",
       :order => "distance"}
   }

   def within_miles(radius)
     self.class.within_miles_of_zip(radius, zip)
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this bit of code:

```
def within_miles(radius)
  self.class.within_miles_of_zip(radius, zip)
end
```

zip is not defined, which is causing your error.  You should consider adding:

```
belongs_to :zip
```

to your user class.